# Okhttp Authenticator multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, authentication, okhttp

I am using `OkHttp` in my android application with several async requests. All requests require a token to be sent with the header. Sometimes I need to refresh the token using a RefreshToken, so I decided to use `OkHttp`'s `Authenticator` class.

What will happen when 2 or more async requests get a 401 response code from the server at the same time? Would the Authenticator's `authenticate()` method be called for each request, or it will only called once for the first request that got a 401?

```
@Override
public Request authenticate(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException
{                
    return null;
}
```

How to refresh token only once?

Comment: check out my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77206302/11671900

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Use a singleton `Authenticator`
2. Make sure the method you use to manipulate the token is `Synchronized`
3. Count the number of retries to prevent excessive numbers of refresh
   token calls
4. Make sure the API calls to get a fresh token and the
   local storage transactions to save the new token in your local stores are not asynchronous. Or if you want to make them asynchronous make sure you to you token related stuff after they are completed.
5. Check if the access token is refreshed by another thread already to
   avoid requesting a new access token from back-end

Here is a sample in Kotlin

```
@SingleTon
class TokenAuthenticator @Inject constructor(
    private val tokenRepository: TokenRepository
) : Authenticator {
    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
        return if (isRequestRequiresAuth(response)) {
            val request = response.request()
            authenticateRequestUsingFreshAccessToken(request, retryCount(request) + 1)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    private fun retryCount(request: Request): Int =
        request.header("RetryCount")?.toInt() ?: 0

    @Synchronized
    private fun authenticateRequestUsingFreshAccessToken(
        request: Request,
        retryCount: Int
    ): Request? {
        if (retryCount > 2) return null

        tokenRepository.getAccessToken()?.let { lastSavedAccessToken ->
            val accessTokenOfRequest = request.header("Authorization") // Some string manipulation needed here to get the token if you have a Bearer token

            if (accessTokenOfRequest != lastSavedAccessToken) {
                return getNewRequest(request, retryCount, lastSavedAccessToken)
            }
        }

        tokenRepository.getFreshAccessToken()?.let { freshAccessToken ->
            return getNewRequest(request, retryCount, freshAccessToken)
        }

        return null
    }

    private fun getNewRequest(request: Request, retryCount: Int, accessToken: String): Request {
        return request.newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
            .header("RetryCount", "$retryCount")
            .build()
    }

    private fun isRequestRequiresAuth(response: Response): Boolean {
        val header = response.request().header("Authorization")
        return header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this code assume the _original_ request already had an Authorization header before it does anything? Do you require the app code to provide that?

Comment: @mabi I do not know if that is what you mean but you may try to use an interceptor to distinguish the endpoints that require Authorization header and apply the TokenAuthenticatorfor only those endpoints.

Comment: The way I understand this is that OkHttp will call `authenticate` on a 401/403 response, you then test for an Authorization header in `isRequestRequiresAuth`, returning null when there's none. So if the original request doesn't already have an Authorization header you abort the request?

Comment: According to the documentation, the authenticate method will react to HTTP 401 unauthorized responses only. If your original request cannot answer the authentication demand then the authenticate method will return null.

Comment: `synchronized` is blocking the current thread so it is likely to lead the application to be unresponsive, right?

Comment: It won't block the thread, it will just prevent other threads to write until the current thread is done with its job.

Answer (score 4):

I see here two scenarios based on how API which you call works.

First one is definitely easier to handle - calling new credentials (e.g. access token) doesn't expire old one. To achieve it you can add an extra flag to your credentials to say that credentials are being refreshed. When you got 401 response, you set flag to true, make a request to get new credentials and you save them only if flag equals true so only first response will be handled and rest of them will be ignored. Make sure that your access to flag is synchronized.

Another scenario is a little bit more tricky - every time when you call new credentials old one are set to be expired by server side. To handle it you I would introduce new object to be used as a semafore - it would be blocked every time when 'credentials are being refreshed'. To make sure that you'll make only one 'refresh credentials' call, you need to call it in block of code which is synchronized with flag. It can look like it:

```
synchronized(stateObject) {
   if(!stateObject.isBeingRefreshed) return;
   Response response = client.execute(request);
   apiClient.setCredentials(response.getNewCredentials());
   stateObject.isBeingRefreshed = false;
}
```

As you've noticed there is an extra check `if(!stateObject.isBeingRefreshed) return;` to cancel requesting new credentials by following requests which received 401 response.

Comment: That way, you lose the requests that are returned, isn't it? With the way I put below, you can call that requests again.

Comment: Which scenario do you mean? If server doesn't expire old access token when new one is generated, imo you doesn't need to block it and it isn't a problem when we lose any because we'll still have an access token which work. Of course it defends how your system works. In second scenario I described how to prevent invoking more 'refresh access token' requests in the first place (synchronized block will prevent doing it), so nothing will be lost.

Comment: That's true, If server doesn't expire old access is no needed to block the old requests. Thanks for the aclaration.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I implemented the `Authenticator` using the Singleton pattern. You can made synchronized that method `authenticate`. In his implementation, I check if the token from the request (getting the `Request` object from `Response` object received in the params of authenticate method) is the same that the saved in the device (I save the token in a `SharedPreferences` object).

If the token is the same, that means that it has not been refresed yet, so I execute the token refresh and the current request again.

If the token is not the same, that means that it has been refreshed before, so I execute the request again but using the token saved in the device.

If you need more help, please tell me and I will put some code here.

Comment: I think it would be good to add info that token needs to be saved by "commit" method instead of "apply" to make it synchronous.

Comment: Hi @antonicg. Can you please provide some code? I am trying to find a way to handle instances where different threads may attempt a refresh at the same time. It sounds like your answer could solve my problem, but the synchronization is where I am stuck and don't quite understand.

Comment: Hi @JPM I don't have this code nowadays. but you have to implement the interface Authenticator on a class and note the method authenticate as synchronized. If you configure that class as Singleton you only have one instance of it and only one thread will access at time to the synchronized method. You set a flag or something where you note when you refreshed the token and you will achieve it.

Comment: No worries @antonicg! Only question I have left is are you suggesting I need some lock inside a synchronized authenticate method? I was under the impression as soon as I mark the method as synchronized, I do not need a lock or anything like that since it will pause executions until the current thread exits the method. My authenticator also uses shared preferences so I was thinking your suggestion of comparing the request token with what is saved should be enough?

Comment: @JPM Yes, you are right, you don't need any lock if you mark the method as synchronized

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution to make sure to **refresh token only once** in a multi-threading case, using `okhttp3.Authenticator`:

```
class Reauthenticator : Authenticator {

    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response?): Request? {
        if (response == null) return null
        val originalRequest = response.request()
        if (originalRequest.header("Authorization") != null) return null // Already failed to authenticate
        if (!isTokenValid()) { // Check if token is saved locally
            synchronized(this) {
                if (!isTokenValid()) { // Double check if another thread already saved a token locally
                    val jwt = retrieveToken() // HTTP call to get token
                    saveToken(jwt)
                }
            }
        }
        return originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", getToken())
                .build()
    }

}
```

You can even write a unit test for this case, too!

Comment: What does the function `isTokenValid()` do? Does that hit the server each time to check that a token is still valid?

Comment: Thanks for your question, I understand it is not obvious. It is just a local check and the implementation will depend on your specific case. I've commented the code to make that more clear.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but one question: when your function is called for a request with a bearer token already in it, that means okhttp has tried that request and it failed. Wouldn't you want to fetch a new token in this case rather than letting the request fall to floor?

Answer (score 0):

Add ***synchronized*** to authenticate() method signature.

And make sure getToken() method is blocking.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public synchronized Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) {

    String newAccessToken = getToken();

    return response.request().newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + newAccessToken)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use singleton custom Authenticator
When refreshing token successful return request with new token else return null.

```
class TokenAuthenticator(
    private val sharedPref: SharedPref,
    private val tokenRefreshApi: TokenRefreshApi
) : Authenticator,
SafeApiCall {

override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
    return runBlocking {
        when (val tokenResponse = getUpdatedToken()) {
            is Resource.Success -> {
                val token = tokenResponse.data.token
                sharedPref.saveToken(token)
                response.request.newBuilder().header("Authorization", "Bearer $token").build()
            }
            else -> {
                null
            }
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun getUpdatedToken(): Resource<LoginResponse> {
    return safeApiCall { tokenRefreshApi.refreshToken("Bearer ${sharedPref.getToken()}") }
}
}
```